# Fluid width div inside fluid width div with padding

Tags: css

I'm having a little problem, i have 2 divs, both have % width.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2 class="title"></h2>
</div>

.wrapper{
  width:50%;
}
.title{
 width:100%;
padding:5px
}
```

[image]

But when i render, the h2 width goes more than the wrapper's width.

Even using padding .title doesnt have to respect wrapper's width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
.wrapper { overflow: hidden; }
```

In this case the .title is still overlapping but it's hidden

Or:

```
.title { width: calc(100% - 10px); }
```

No IE8 support.